# Prolog Question - Transform an Array of elements into a Set of elements

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate to transform an array of elements into a set of elements. In order to do so, I have created the following predicates in swi-prolog:

```
sterge(_, [], []).

sterge(A, [A|L], New):-
    sterge(A, L, New).

sterge(A, [B|L], [B|New]):-
 A \= B,
 sterge(A, L, New).

multime(A, New):-
 mult(A, [], New).

mult([], A, A).

mult([A|L], [A|T], New):-
 sterge(A, L, L1),
 mult(L1, T, New).
```

As you can see, the `sterge` predicate, takes 3 arguments. Its main purpose is to delete all the appearances of the `A` element into the `L` list, resulting the `New` list which doesn't contain any `A` elements.

With the help of this predicate, I have tried to eliminate all the elements from a list, one by one, including all their appearances and add them to a new list which contains a single copy of the elements of the given array which is required to be transformed into a set of elements.

The `mult` predicate takes 3 arguments.

The first argument is the given array which has to be transformed into a set.

The second argument is a buffer list used to contain the unique elements of the array, one by one during the execution of the predicate.

And the third argument is used to return the complete set of arguments.

Practically, I wanted the third argument to be unified with the value of the second argument, when the given array, the first argument, is null(`[]`).

And finally, the `multime` predicate who takes two arguments( the given array and the desired set) launches a call over the `mult` predicate with the following values for its arguments. For the first argument it takes the given array, for the second argument, the null list(`[]`), and for the third argument, the desired set of elements, which needs to be obtained.

However, when I launch a call for the `multime` predicate, I always receive the `false`result. Could you please tell me where do I go wrong?

Comment: please provide some invocations of `sterge`, `mult`, and `multime` and the actual and expected results.

Comment: I have tested `sterge` predicate and it works just fine. For example, for the element `1` and the list `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]` the expected result should be `[2, 2, 3, 4]`. If you launch the call `sterge(1, [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3, 4])` you should receive the `true` value. On the other hand, `multime`, and `mult` doesn't work properly. I mean, for every values which I introduce, I receive the `false` value in return. The expected result should be:

Comment: `multime([1,2,2,3,3,4,4], [1,2,3,4]).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the body of your `mult` is broken.

```
mult([A|L], [A|T], New):-
 sterge(A, L, L1),
 mult(L1, T, New).
```

you are spliting the list of the first argument AND of the second argument. `mult` is called from `multime` with an empty list as second argument. the empty list cannot be splitted and so that predicate cannot match. that is why you are getting a `false`.

here is the fixed code

```
mult([A|L], T, New):-
  sterge(A, L, L1),
  mult(L1, [A|T], New).
```

the list concatenating is done in the recursive call to `mult`. the recursion will end when `L1` is an empty list, and the concatenated list will be returned via the `New` variable. note: the new list will be in reversed order.